# Undoing last point when drawing linestring in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I would like to be able to draw a linestring and to be able to undo the last drawn point when the key ESC is pressed.

I used that code when I first wrote my application :

```
  // create the interaction
  draw_interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vector_layer.getSource(),
    type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ ($geom_type.val())
  });
    // add it to the map
  map.addInteraction(draw_interaction);

  // when a new feature has been drawn...
  draw_interaction.on('drawstart', function(evt) {
    var feature = evt.feature;
    var geom = feature.getGeometry();
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
      if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        if (geom.getType() === "LineString") {
          var coords = geom.getCoordinates();
          var len = coords.length;
          console.log("undo");
          if (len > 1) {
           geom.setCoordinates(geom.getCoordinates().slice(0, len - 1));
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

You can see a live version on codepen following that link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waPXyG

My problem is when I upgraded from 3.5.0 to 3.6.0, the behaviour changed :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVOrrq

As you can see on the live example, when undoing (pressing ESC) it seems to be working but when you want to add a new point to the linestring, the points I removed are back in place. Looks like a caching behaviour as been added to 3.6.0

I hope someone can help me, it's either a regression or a api modification that I did not notice in the change log.

Comment: My guess is that you have to rethink your logic. For example, if you add a `keyup` listener every `drawstart` this becomes unmanaged.

Comment: In my code, I remove the event listener on drawend event. I did not copy all my code for the sake of simplicity in the codepen exemple. I am glad if you could provide me with a better design, I guess I am not the only one who needs to manage undos in my webapp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since OpenLayers 3.9.0, this is as simple as using the `removeLastPoint` method of the `DrawInteraction`.  So you can do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 27)
        draw_interaction.removeLastPoint()
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Since v3.6.0, a `geometryFunction` is used to return the geometry resulting from drawing with `ol.interaction.Draw`. This `geometryFunction` is where you modify the geometry during drawing. So what you can do is set an undo flag to true when the user hits the Esc key. In the `geometryFunction` you change the coordinates when the flag was set:

```
var undo = false; // set this to true in the Esc key handler
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  // ...
  geometryFunction: function(coords, geom) {
    if (!geom) {
      geom = new ol.geom.LineString(null);
    }
    if (undo) {
      if (coords.length > 1) {
        coords.pop();
      }
      undo = false;
    }
    geom.setCoordinates(coords);
    return geom;
  }
});
```

Comment: That's right. This is the correct way to do this. But could you explain me why [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NUQa96?p=preview) doesn't works. I'm just trying an immediate (visual) to your solution.

Comment: @ahocevar:  I've seen that function at lunch time and was goingto give it a try, you saved me some time, thank you for that :)

Comment: @ahocevar: your function did the jopb, whoever I have a little question, when using a polygon shape, I have coords[0][0] = Array[2] (0: 571349.7961789053 1: 5722147.431410865) instead of coords[0] = Array[2] is it an expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes, this is expected. A polygon is made up of rings. One outer ring and zero or more inner rings.

Comment: @JonatasWalker There are several issues with your plunker. I created a working fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ei6jGd6alOJPNYFTpns. Basically what you have to do is update the coordinates in the geometryFunction after an undo.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the update "on esc" was the missing part.

Comment: The code was working fine, but since I switched to ol3 3.9.0, pressing the esc key does nothing if the mouse does not move... any idea?

Comment: I also used the same solution for undoing, but there is a problem seems to be a bug. if you undo a point and then finish your line at a point close to the same point just being undone, then the last segment will be removed, Why?

Answer (score 1):

I've made some tests and this can be done with something like this:

Set a custom listener to your draw interaction.

```
draw.set('escKey', '');
```

Set a global variable if drawing start, and store the created feature:

```
draw.on('drawstart', function(evt){
    drawing = true;
    drawing_feature = evt.feature;
});
```

Set a keydown listener to the document and if drawing is active, fire your custom event:

```
var keydown = function(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode === 27 && drawing === true){ //esc key
        //dispatch event
        draw.set('escKey', Math.random());
    }
};
document.addEventListener('keydown', keydown, false);
```

And then slice the lineString coordinates:

```
draw.on('change:escKey', function(evt){

    var geom = drawing_feature.getGeometry();
    var coords = geom.getCoordinates();
    var len = coords.length;
    if (len > 1) {
        var new_coordinates = coords.slice(0, len - 1);

        geom.setCoordinates(new_coordinates); //this is just visual
        //this (target.e) is the equivalent of this.sketchCoords_ in debug mode
        evt.target.e = new_coordinates;
    }
});
```

Now, notice this `evt.target.e`, or `this.sketchCoords_` in ol-debug.js. This is a temporary/internal array of coords, perhaps, there's a better way to do this. I've tried a lot of others options and this was the only way.

Maybe a core developer can show us a better approach.

Oh yes, [a working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HdR1rG?p=preview).

Comment: That's really nice to have dedicated some of your precious time on this. Appreciate it! I'm curious to see if a core dev can give some input as well :)

Comment: You should not rely on properties like `evt.target.e`, because `e` is a symbol of the minified build and is neither API nor stable.