# Where is the drawn feature when the drawend is triggered in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, intersection, events

I have written a piece of code to check if the drawn line is intersecting other lines in the vector layer. If so, then the line should be split and new lines should be added to the layer. here is my code:

The events:

```
lineStringdraw.on('drawend', function(e2) {
var featureEnd = e2.feature;
var featureGeom = featureEnd.getGeometry();
var endNodeCoordinates = featureGeom.getLastCoordinate();
snapIndex= endNodeCoordinates.length-1;
checkSnapping(nodes, endNodeCoordinates);
if(snap){
    var featureCoordinates = featureGeom.getCoordinates();
    featureCoordinates[featureCoordinates.length-1]= snapToNode;
    featureGeom.setCoordinates(featureCoordinates);
    featureEnd.setGeometry(featureGeom);
    featureEnd.changed();
}
checkIntersection(featureEnd);
if (tempList.length!==0){
    //lineStringdraw.finishDrawing();    //my first solutuion
    //vector2.getSource().getFeatures().removeFeature([vector2.getSource().getFeatures().length-1]);
    //delete e2.feature;   //my second solotion.
    for (i=0;i<tempList.length;i++){vector2.getSource().addFeature(tempList[i]);}   
}

drawing = false;
drawing_feature = null;
});
```

**checkIntersection():**

this function checks if the currently drawn line is intersecting other lines. if so then it calls the split function which will produce final lines to be added to the layer.

There is only one problem. The currently drawn line is also added to the vector layer and I cannot stop it as this feature is not yet added to the source so I cannot remove it from source. And also I cannot remove it from the draw interaction (at least I dont know how to remove it). It seems that the line is added after the drawend event is handled but how I can prevent it from happening. Any Idea?

**EDIT**

I now use the addfeature event for the source. when the feature is added, it will be checked for the intersection. but there rises another problem: when I add the new features from split function they will be checked again and again. I tried .unByKey() to remove the listener so that I can add the new features but then I cannot reactivate it.

```
var addFeatureEventListener = vector2.getSource().on('addfeature', function(e){
var currentFeture = vector2.getSource().getFeatures()[vector2.getSource().getFeatures().length-1]; 
var newLines =  checkIntersection(currentFeture);
vector2.getSource().unByKey(addFeatureEventListener);
console.info("the listener is deactivated now....");
vector2.getSource().addFeatures(newLines);
vector2.getSource().changed();  
});
```

I am kinda fed up. I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31112149/1388084) but I seem cannot understand it.

Comment: I guess you'll need [`ol.interaction.DrawGeometryFunctionType()`](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.html#.DrawGeometryFunctionType) - check this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152646/50718

Comment: @JonatasWalker: As far as I understood the geometryFunction, it is being called while the line is being drawn and once the drawend is triggered, the geometryFunction is not callable.

Comment: How does this end up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the edited version of my question and revising a bit more, my problem is now resolved. Here is the final code:

```
var addFeatureEventListener = vector2.getSource().on('addfeature', addFeatureFunction);

function addFeatureFunction(e){
var currentFeture = vector2.getSource().getFeatures()[vector2.getSource().getFeatures().length-1]; 
var newLines =  checkIntersection(currentFeture);
vector2.getSource().unByKey(addFeatureEventListener);
console.info("the listener is deactivated now....");
vector2.getSource().addFeatures(newLines);
vector2.getSource().changed(); 
addFeatureEventListener = vector2.getSource().on('addfeature', addFeatureFunction)};
});
```

this helped me to check the recently added feature to the layer for the intersection, then split it and add the new features instead. This may not be the most elegant way but I stick to for now. I try Jonatas's method laterfor upgrading my app.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
lineStringdraw.on('drawstart', function(){
    vector2.getSource().once('addfeature', handleAddFeature);
});

function handleAddFeature(evt) {
    var feature = evt.feature;
    // ...
}
```

Add the listener just when start drawing. OL will remove it for you since you are using `once`.

Comment: you think I can use it in drawend, as I need to check the intersections after the line is drawn. This may be of use if I want to upgrade my code to check the possible intersections while the line is being drawn.

Comment: Actually I solved my problem using the addfeature event by removing the listener and adding a new one when features are added. Now I have another problem which i need to reflect a bit more on it.

Comment: Use the code I posted. Check the intersections inside `handleAddFeature()`.