# How to remove last drawing feature in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I have already found [Undoing last point when drawing linestring in OpenLayers 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152119/undo-last-point-when-drawing-linestring-possible-regression) (with [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ei6jGd6alOJPNYFTpns)) but it can't undo misclicks when drawing polygon. So what I want is remove last drawing.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this -

```
var features = vectorSource.getFeatures();
var lastFeature = features[features.length - 1];
vectorSource.removeFeature(lastFeature);
```

Note that you need to `vectorSource.getFeatures()` every time you want to remove the last feature or use it in a function.

Comment: Hey this works great for me. DO you any idea about redo that feature again.

Comment: `vectorSource.addFeature(lastFeature)` should work. If you are removing multiple features and want to redo them, may be you should store the features somewhere before you remove them.

Comment: this removeFeatures actually deletes feature, so on that index we get undefined value.

Comment: Oh. [`Clone`](http://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.Feature.html#clone) the feature then? `var cloneFeature = lastFeature.clone();`